# Load Image From Local Location?

Tags: html

I tried to load local images into html image using this line code.

```
<img src="file://C:/local/images/aaa.jpg" alt="Images" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

This code is only working on internet explorer, not working on either chrome or Firefox. As i googled earlier version of Mozilla supported this. But Chrome never supported this. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there any solution to support all browsers.

Comment: Hope this link will help:https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2664790?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes, Firefox (and probably Chrome also) do not support links to local files : [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work)

To have a cross browser solution, you need to set to the `src` a path relative to your project.

Assuming your HTML page is in `C:/local/` you will need to set the image `src` to `images/aaa.jpg`

```
<img src="images/aaa.jpg" alt="Images" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

If you are using a local server, you may need an absolute path:

```
<img src="/images/aaa.jpg" alt="Images" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```